# I'm trying to understand a query I've written for PostgreSQL / PostGIS

Tags: postgresql, gis, postgis

I have created a table that contains a list of all postal codes in the United States. I am trying to query this table to get a list of all zip codes within a certain radius of a given zip code. I am using PostgreSQL 9.3 with the PostGIS extension.

## The Table

```
CREATE TABLE city
(
  city_id serial NOT NULL,
  region_id integer,
  country_id integer,
  name text NOT NULL,
  postal_code text,
  longitude real,
  latitude real,
  geom geometry(Point,4326),
  CONSTRAINT city_id_pk PRIMARY KEY (city_id)
  WITH (FILLFACTOR=100),
  CONSTRAINT country_id_fk FOREIGN KEY (country_id)
      REFERENCES country (country_id) MATCH FULL
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT region_id_fk FOREIGN KEY (region_id)
      REFERENCES region (region_id) MATCH FULL
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE city
  OWNER TO personnelity092014;


CREATE INDEX idx_city_geom
  ON city
  USING gist
  (geom);
```

## The Creation of geom Column:

```
SELECT AddGeometryColumn ('public','city','geom',4326,'POINT',2);

UPDATE city SET geom = ST_PointFromText('POINT(' || longitude || ' ' || latitude || ')', 4326);
```

## The Query

```
SELECT z.postal_code
  FROM city z, city z2
  WHERE z2.postal_code = '59801' 
    AND st_expand(z2.geom, .1) && z.geom   
    AND st_distance(z.geom, z2.geom) <= .1;
```

OK, great, it gives me zip codes that are around the area, so I know I am on the right track. However, what the heck is .1? At first I was going with 10, thinking 10 miles (yeah right), but I was getting zip codes all the way in Alaska (59801 is in Montana), so I knew 10 was not right. What I am trying to understand is how I can specify the distance in miles.

I've searched Google and tried some queries I've found in my searches, but none of the queries I've tried have worked--most of them gave me zip codes in Alaska. I'm beginning to think that I possibly created my geom column incorrectly. I'm more interested in understanding the query I've written than having someone write a query that "just works" for me. If anyone could illuminate for me, it'd be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so I figured it out. If you follow most guides from a Google search, you will be directed to create a geometry column (e.g., [this guide](http://unserializableone.blogspot.com/2007/02/using-postgis-to-find-points-of.html)). However, when doing a radius search, it seems that geography is what you want (unless you have a GIS degree and actually know how the heck to use a geom column). In fact, the PostGIS documentation for ST_DWithin makes this pretty clear:

> For Geometries: The distance is specified in units defined by the spatial reference system of the geometries. For this function to make sense, the source geometries must both be of the same coordinate projection, having the same SRID.
>
> For geography units are in meters and measurement is defaulted to use_spheroid=true (measure around WGS 84 spheroid), for faster check, use_spheroid=false to measure along sphere.

So, with this in mind, and not entirely understanding "units defined by spatial reference system of the geometries." I did the following to set up a geography column:

```
-- Create the geography column
ALTER TABLE city ADD COLUMN geography geography(Point,4326); 
-- Populate it
UPDATE city SET geography = ST_GeographyFromText('SRID=4326;POINT(' || st_x(geom) || ' ' ||  st_y(geom) || ')');
```

Alright, so now when I do the following query:

```
SELECT z.postal_code
FROM city z, city z2
WHERE z2.postal_code = '59801'    
    AND st_dwithin(z.geography, z2.geography, 16093);
```

I get a list of zip codes within a radius of 16093 meters, or ~10 miles, of 59801. Exactly what I wanted.

Comment: units defined by spatial reference system of the geometries basically means either degrees or meters, depending on whether geographic or projected.

Comment: use `geom::geography` for your "Populate it" step, as it is direct and converts other geometry types too. Also, the convention is to call this column `geog`, but there's nothing wrong with naming a column the same as it's type, as you have done.